# Get Zendesk Logins for a User based on a time period from the API

Tags: c#, zendesk-api

I'm trying to find a workaround for getting logins for the past 7 days of a User in Zendesk via the API.  Unlike some of the other endpoints Zendesk offers, this one doesn't have sideloading to get this information.  https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/users

I've looked at the audit log endpoint also to see if I could get this information and add to my new user object, but it also doesn't offer that sort of information either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the sessions endpoint? I don't believe it will retain for seven days nor can it be sideloaded.  You'd have to run daily and then compare the IDs with your users. https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/sessions

Comment: I went down the Sessions path on Friday, and you're correct that it doesn't persist.  Plus having an open Session doesn't necessarily correlate with a login on a specific day.  For the time being I'm just going to persist the last_logon_at information everyday from the user endpoint into a database.  Seems kind of hoakey, but it's better than what is currently being offered via the API.